# Discussion replies show as 'Dispform.aspx' in search results

Tags: search, xslt

Search results show 'dispform.aspx' as the page title on replies to discussion posts.

Ideally i'd want it to say 'RE: discussion title'.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

EDIT - should probably point out that we have dozens of discussion forums and new ones are being created all the time. so any solution will have to be generic.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think you can use Advanced Search Box web part + Search Core Results web part or of course customize exist search page.

With custom xslt in Search Core Result web part (and some other settings, as main with managed properties in "Selected columns") you can create any view which can depends on search results, on result item type or any item field (after configure needed managed properties and search areas in SSP).

Just look at [this post](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2007/10/28/moss-2007-customize-the-search-result-using-xslt-part-3-customize-using-sharepoint-designer-2007.aspx) or [this good post](http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/customizing-search-series-finally-customizing-the-search-results) and also [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5Y95rDmydA).

I think it'll get the right result.

Comment: links are busted